# NSJSONSerialization works on IOS 6 but not on IOS 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, nsjsonserialization

I'm working on restoring iOS 5.1 compatibility to an app I shipped which requires 6.0 currently.

This code works perfectly under 6.0 but when running under 5.1 parsing returns a null object and an error when parsing the exact same JSON result.

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

if ((responseData == nil) || (responseDict == nil)) {
   // I only get here when running on 5.1            
}
```

I tried weak linking the Foundation framework.  The `jsonError` is

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Duplicate key for object around character 8.) UserInfo=0x11d58530 {NSDebugDescription=Duplicate key for object around character 8.}

I have validated my JSON and there is only a single instance of the object type at character 8 and character 8 is simply a colon:

```
{"site":{
```

Comment: I'm thinking there were some bugs in the iOS 5 implementation.  You might be better off using one of the other JSON parsers such as JSONKit.

Comment: If you post the full JSON response that might help us figure out the problem.